# XSLT flat to hierarchical

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a flat file with xml data that contains parent and child information i need a xslt to transform

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <CRStructure>
    <objid>CA0D2594-183B-4E80-B2CA-4F915A1E2D32</objid>
    <cr_id>87</cr_id>
    <cr_parent>14</cr_parent>
  </CRStructure>
  <CRStructure>
    <objid>23BD80FA-7ACE-4111-9607-8AC0857868AF</objid>
    <cr_id>172</cr_id>
    <cr_parent>128</cr_parent>
  </CRStructure>
  <CRStructure>
    <objid>E381DE99-AD82-428E-A82B-63EB965BA2F4</objid>
    <cr_id>247</cr_id>
    <cr_parent>138</cr_parent>
      </CRStructure>
  <CRStructure> ............
```

To

```
<CR  xmlns="http://ait.com/cr/">

  <CRItems>

    <CRItem ObjectId="69230491-BCB8-4CD5-9FC3-2113FFE832EC">
     <CrId>1</CrId> 

        <CRItems>

        <CRItem ObjectId="2D425940-B3B1-432E-BDA4-6778C9AE8391">
            <CrId>2</CrId>
             <CRItems>

            <CRItem ObjectId="3F2DF482-0485-42C9-A1D2-FCFE0EF6B4E3">
                <CrId>22</CrId>
              </CRItem> .........
```

The hierarchical structure is always three levels , anyone that can point me in the right direction.

**EDIT**

Tried this and it seems to work ,

```
  <xsl:template match="//NewDataSet">
     <CR>
       <CRItems>
     <xsl:for-each select="CRStructure[cr_parent='0']">
       <CRItem>
         <xsl:attribute name="ObjectId">
           <xsl:value-of select="objid" />
         </xsl:attribute>
         <CRItems>
         <xsl:variable name="cridequ" select="cr_id" />
         <xsl:for-each select="//NewDataSet/CRStructure[cr_parent=$cridequ]">
           <CRItem>
             <xsl:attribute name="ObjectId">
               <xsl:value-of select="objid" />
             </xsl:attribute>
             <CRItems>
               <xsl:variable name="cridsub" select="cr_id" />
               <xsl:for-each select="//NewDataSet/CRStructure[cr_parent=$cridsub]">
                 <CRItem>
                   <xsl:attribute name="ObjectId">
                     <xsl:value-of select="objid" />
                   </xsl:attribute>
                 </CRItem>
               </xsl:for-each>
             </CRItems>                          
           </CRItem>
         </xsl:for-each>
         </CRItems>
       </CRItem>   
    </xsl:for-each>
         </CRItems>
     </CR>
  </xsl:template>
```

Not sure if this is the correct way of solving it , seems like most suggestions i find is to use some combinations of  `<xsl:template match....` but not sure how to do this

Comment: tried creating an xslt but with no success

Comment: Consider to post a small but complete input sample and then the corresponding result sample you want to create with XSLT. Currently I don't see any relation with your posted input sample and the posted result sample as the ids don't match between the samples. And please explain how to determine the root element(s) of the result sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are proposing is correct but could be generalized and simplified as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://ait.com/cr/" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="sons" match="CRStructure" use="cr_parent"/>
    <xsl:param name="maxLevels">3</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="NewDataSet">
        <CR>
            <CRItems>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('sons', 0)"/>
            </CRItems>
        </CR>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CRStructure">
        <xsl:param name="level">1</xsl:param>
        <xsl:if test="$level &lt;= $maxLevels">
            <CRItem ObjectId="{objid}">
                <CrId>
                    <xsl:value-of select="cr_id"/>
                </CrId>
                <CRItems>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('sons', cr_id)">
                        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level  + 1"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </CRItems>
            </CRItem>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The variable $index has been introduced to avoid to loop forever if there is an error in your input document ;) ...